# Why is this different? Currying/Higher Order Functions

Tags: python

I'm wondering why these 2 pieces of code are different?

This code gives me the answer of 5

```py
curry2 = lambda f: lambda x: lambda y: f(x, y)
m = curry2(add)
m(2)(3)
5
```

This one gives me the location of my function

```py
def lambda_curry2(func):
    return lambda f: lambda x: lambda y: f(x, y)

curry2 = lambda_curry2(add)
add_three = curry2(3)
add_three(5)
```

Comment: You should pass `func` as the argument to the first lambda in `lambda_curry2`. Have you looked into [functool.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one isn't using `func`. You don't need as many lambdas, because `func` is the function you want to call.

So it should be;

```
def lambda_curry2(func):
    return lambda x: lambda y: func(x, y)
```

Put another way, your definition of `curry2` is equivalent to:

```
def curry2(f):
    return lambda x: lambda y: f(x, y)
```

In general,

```
name = lambda <vars>: <expression>
```

is short for

```
def name(<vars>):
    return <expression>
```

`lambda` is usually used when you don't need to name the function (e.g. when you want to pass a simple function as an argument or return it as a value).